# How to create database using angular2+ in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, angular, couchdb

I am trying to create a database in couchdb using angular2+. I have created a button when clicked on button the database should be created.
But I am getting error.

```
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","url":"http://127.0.0.1:5984/myproject","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:5984/myproject: 401 Unauthorized","error":{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}}"
at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
at eval (zone.js:741)
at eval (zone.js:757)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
at Zone.run (zone.js:150)
at eval (zone.js:889)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

can someone help me how to do it?  I have added the code below.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
interface Resp {
id: string;
ok: boolean;
rev: string;
}
@Component({
selector: "app-databasse",
templateUrl: "./databasse.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./databasse.component.css"]
})
export class DatabasseComponent {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
books = [
{ id: 1, name: "Core Java" },
{ id: 2, name: "Angular 2" },
{ id: 3, name: "Hibernate" }
];

async createDatabase(): Promise<Resp> {
return new Promise<Resp>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.put<Resp>(`http://127.0.0.1:5984/myproject`, this.books).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log('created document: ' + res.id)
            resolve(res)
        },
        err => {
            reject(err)
        }
    )
 })
 }
 }
------template file------
<p>
<button (click)="createDatabase()">createDatabase</button>
</p>
```

Comment: But... Angular can't "create a database". It runs in a browser, and your database resides on the server, that's a different machine...

Comment: @JeremyThille  when I used "Get" it works. request const test = new Promise<Resp>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get<Resp>(`http://127.0.0.1:5984/myproject/_all_docs`).subscribe(
   res => {
    resolve(res)
   },
   err => {
    reject(err)
   }
  )
 })
 console.log(test.then(data => data))
 return test
  }
        },
        err => {
            reject(err)
        }
    )
 })

Comment: But Angular only called your backend. Your backend created the database. Angular didn't do anything other than calling to your server on the `/myproject` route. Probably your server doesn't have a `PUT /myproject` route configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't really try to create a database but rather attempts to add documents (books) to an existing database. Creating a database and inserting a bulk of documents cannot be done in a single HTTP call. I'll answer the question on how to create a CouchDB database from Angular.

For [creating a database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#put--db), CouchDB Server Administrator privileges are required. Therefore you need to submit corresponding credentials (username and password) together with your HTTP request. There exists different ways of authentication, but you could start with [basic authentication](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#basic-authentication), a quick and simple way to authenticate with CouchDB.

In your Angular code, you're using the [`HttpClient.put()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put) method to send a PUT request to CouchDB. This request should also include an `options` object that contains some required [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) together with the property `withCredentials: true`. This `options` object could be created as follows. You obviously need to replace ":" with real values.

```
createHttpOptions(): any {
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("<username>:<password>"));
  return { headers: httpHeaders, withCredentials: true };
}
```

Please have a look at the [`CouchDBService`](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/backend/couchdb/couchdb.service.ts) from the open source project [**Koia**](https://github.com/centeractive/koia). It illustrates in more detail on how to communicate with CouchDB from Angular. The class actually also contains a `createDatabase` method.

> To make your HTTP requests work, make sure to configure CORS by changing [http] and [cors] entries within the configuration file $COUCHDB_HOME/etc/local.ini as explained [here](https://github.com/centeractive/koia#installing).