# Get 401 when using ajax call to retrieve data from couchdb

Tags: javascript, ajax, couchdb

I try to use ajax call in js file to retrieve data from couchdb.

But I got the 401 error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Here is my js code:

```js
var locate_data = $.ajax({
  url: 'http://admin:mypassword@localhost:5984/database_name',
  type:'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log("successfully loaded."), 
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
       console.log("error"), 
       alert(xhr.statusText)
   }
})
```

I can use 'curl GET' to get the data from couchdb by using the terminal.

What is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) where requests contain a header field in the form of `Authorization: Basic <credentials>`, where credentials is the `Base64` encoding of username and password, joined by a single colon '`:`'.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62967379/2358409) explains how to do the same in the context of `Angular`. I'm not using `Ajax` myself but I suppose it should look something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:5984/database_name',
  type:'GET',      
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type', 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("<username>:<password>")
  },
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
  },
  ...
```